I can't import one qml file into another, the same reflection in CMake when setting up a Qt QML project
When I just create a project and write cmake, everything goes well, when I start adding new qml files and then perform the configuration, then 2 warnings come out:
 CMake Warning (dev) at /home/zxctatar/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:3378 (message):
  Qt policy QTP0004 is not set: You need qmldir files for each extra
  directory that contains .qml files for your module.  Check
  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-cmake-policy-qtp0004.html for policy details.
  Use the qt_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):   
/home/zxctatar/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Qml/Qt6QmlMacros.cmake:3238 
(__qt_internal_setup_policy)   
/home/zxctatar/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Qml/Qt6QmlMacros.cmake:891 
(qt6_target_qml_sources)   
/home/zxctatar/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Qml/Qt6QmlMacros.cmake:1148 
(qt6_add_qml_module)   CMakeLists.txt:15 (qt_add_qml_module) This 
warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

I already followed this link, but I didn’t find any useful information for myself (maybe I was looking poorly), but I realized that the whole point is in qmldir, I struggled with it for a long time, but nothing came of it anyway, at the moment the CMake file and The file locations look like this:
File tree
Client/
├──build\
├──src\
│   ├──styles\
│   │   └──Colors.qml
│   ├──view\
│   │   ├──loginwindow\
│   │   │   └──LoginWindow.qml
│   ├──main.cpp
├──CMakeLists.txt
└──CMakeLists.txt.user

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(Client VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.5)

qt_add_executable(appClient
    src/main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appClient
    URI Client
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES

        QML_FILES src/view/loginwindow/LoginWindow.qml
        QML_FILES src/styles/Colors.qml
)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
set_target_properties(appClient PROPERTIES
#    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.appClient
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(appClient
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS appClient
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

There is also a problem with importing one qml file into another, in this case Colors in LoginWindow, when I specify the path to the file, the project is built, but when launched it gives the following error:
qrc:/qt/qml/Client/src/view/loginwindow/LoginWindow.qml:3:1: "../../styles/Colors.qml": no such directory

LoginWindow.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls
import "../../styles/Colors.qml" as Colors

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    color: Colors.backgroundColor
}

Colors.qml
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.15

QtObject {
    property color backgroundColor: "#DDEFFF"
}

I also tried to use qmldir files and qrc, but nothing worked, maybe I did something wrong
I’m still trying to figure out QML and CMake, I spent almost two days searching for the problem, so if this is a stupid situation, don’t be strict, I’ll be grateful for any help
OC: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

UPDATE
I built the project provided in Qt (calqlatr), it also gives exactly the same warnings.
Also when I changed these lines in CMakeLists.txt:
qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.5)
qt_add_executable(appClient
    src/main.cpp
)
qt_add_qml_module(appClient
    URI Client
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES

        QML_FILES src/view/loginwindow/LoginWindow.qml
        QML_FILES src/styles/Colors.qml
)

for these:
qt6_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.5)
qt6_add_executable(appClient
    src/main.cpp
)
qt6_add_qml_module(appClient
    URI Client
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES

        QML_FILES src/view/loginwindow/LoginWindow.qml
        QML_FILES src/styles/Colors.qml
)

then this line no longer appears:
/home/zxctatar/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Qml/Qt6QmlMacros.cmake:1148 
    (qt6_add_qml_module)


I see you are using QT 6.8.0. In that case add:
qt_policy(SET QTP0004 NEW)

to your CMakelists.txt file, inbetween "qt_add_executable" and "qt
_add_qml_module" sections. That should solve the warnings. (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-cmake-policy-qtp0004.html)
As for the Color.qml import. You might try adding it as a module instead of a relative path.

thank you, this really helped solve the problem with warnings, could you tell me how to import Color.qml as a module, as I understand it, this is done through the qmldir file, but I already tried to do it using it and it doesn’t work

You should avoid asking more than one question per post on StackOverflow. Colors.qml is already part of the same module as LoginWindow.qml. You shouldn't need any import statement at all. If you do use an import, it should look like this: import Client since that's what you named your module.

unfortunately this doesn't work, when I write an import client I get a warning
Warnings occurred while importing module "Client": [import]

About the module. As JarMan pointed out, Colors.qml is already part of the same module because of:
qt6_add_qml_module(appClient
    URI Client
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES

        QML_FILES src/view/loginwindow/LoginWindow.qml
        QML_FILES src/styles/Colors.qml
)

Afaik you can use color: backgroundColor and delete the import if I'm right.
Or create a module for the "Styles" folder. In a CMakelists.txt file in the Styles folder with content:
qt6_add_qml_module(Styles
URI Styles
VERSION 1.0
QML_FILES
    QML_FILES Colors.qml

)
Also needed in the Styles folder is a qmldir file:
module Styles
Colors 1.0 Colors.qml

Now you should be able to import Styles as Styles, including the Colors. color: Styles.backgroundColor
